# Where's the Geary send icon/button?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I click on 'Compose new message', compose my message and then what? I don't see a button or icon for send. (If I reply to a message I see a blue 'postage stamp' icon for send. But nothing at all for a new message.)

Comment: Marking this as "offtopic" since it is a bug and that is offtopic for SE.

Comment: Agreed, this is a known bug with a fix in the works.

Comment: Sorry for reporting this issue in the wrong way. Thanks for all the fast replies. If this is a known bug, what is the bug #? I'd like to track it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Same here. The buttons only appear when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to compose the message in a new window.

There also seems to be no shortcut to send to get around this, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> just opens another previously hidden search box.

Answer (score 2):

Even if all the controls are missing, you can send an email by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.